# How to calculate outline of complex polygon in Android maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, polygon

I need to fill the center of a polygon in Android maps v2 and am running into problems when the polygon is complex and has lines that cross each other. The user is able to draw on the map with their finger and then I use a map projection to convert my points to LatLng.

I need to fill the center even if it is drawn with lines that cross.

My code to draw is as follows:

```
    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    rectOptions.strokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    rectOptions.fillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_map_fill));
    rectOptions.strokeWidth(4);
    rectOptions.addAll(latLngs);
    mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
```

Screenshot when I draw a star with the lines crossing:
[image]

Screenshot when I draw the star with only the outline:
[image]

Is there a way to calculate what LatLngs make up the outline or is there a different solution?

EDIT: The iOS version of the app I'm working on handles this perfectly..they just add all the points to a polygon and Google Maps figures it out. At this point I believe this is a bug/feature that is lacking from Android Google Maps.

EDIT: Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=6255

Comment: Do you solve this issue.I am facing the same problem

Comment: No I did not and the bug report hasn't gone anywhere either.

Comment: Found any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's already a year gone but here is my solution.
I use the [JTS library](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm), I think you can use a client of this library as well, to create the surrounding polygon.

This method creates a new list of [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) objects which you can use to draw the surrounding polygon of your input.

```
private void createSurroundingPolygon(List<LatLng> polygonPath) {
    List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (LatLng latLng : polygonPath) {
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(latLng.longitude, latLng.latitude));
    }

    GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();
    Geometry lineString = factory.createLineString(coordinates.toArray(new Coordinate[coordinates.size()]));
    Polygon polygon = (Polygon) BufferOp.bufferOp(lineString, 0.0001);

    Coordinate[] coordinatesSurroundingPolygon = polygon.getExteriorRing().getCoordinates();
    List<LatLng> surroundingPolygon = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < coordinatesSurroundingPolygon.length; i++) {
        surroundingPolygon.add(new LatLng(coordinatesSurroundingPolygon[i].y, coordinatesSurroundingPolygon[i].x));
    }
    drawPolygon(surroundingPolygon);
}
```

First it creates a new list of Coordindates. They are used to create a JTS Geometry, i.e. a LineString. You can't create a LinearRing or a Polygon directly from your coordinates list because you don't know if it is a valid (closed polygon without intersections) one. You get a Polygon when you buffer the given Geometry with a distance, in my case 0.0001. The distance is additional space which is added outside to your original polygon.

Finally with the method [Polygon.getExtgeriorRing()](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Polygon.html#getExteriorRing()) you get the outline polygon without any intersections and crossing lines.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to detect where the lines collide with each other then convert those pixel positions to lat/lng points.

you would need to keep track of the first and last point which is the same in your case then check each line with all the other lines in the polygon. Also keep track of the order you find them in based on the direction you start checking (ie. clockwise/counter-clockwise). Convert all the intersection points from x,y to lat/lng.

after you found all the intersection positions then you can start at the first point and create a line the the first intersection point then the next line would be the first intersection point to your next non-intersection point(ie. the tips of the star) etc. etc. until you form a new list of all the new points then give the map that list to plot.

you can use this formula to get started http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection

there may be some holes in my logic that i didnt think of.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't specifically need it to work just for a star, but rather any polygon that is drawn with intersecting lines so I believe this logic would fail if they draw something crazy.